# Is there a way to display a short message to the screen and have it disappear?

Tags: ios

I am looking to display a short message to the screen and have it diappear after a few seconds.  Is there a way to do that?

I am looking at alerts, but it doesn't seem like that is what I need.

What I am looking for is something equivalent of toast messages in Android if that helps explain my question.

Answer (score 4):

Initialize a UIAlertView as normal (called `alertView` here), and then do this wherever you need:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideAlert:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:delay];

-(void)hideAlert:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
      [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: and if I'm not mistaken you can set your button titles to nil so it is only the message that pops up :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at this helpful library:
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/itoast

Comment: iToast, I love it - I bet Apple already have plans for a smart toaster which has built in WiFi so you can pop it up from your iPhone before it burns... ooh the trademark infringements... I can see them now!

Comment: @rooster117 its what I wanted except it looks like a 3rd party thing I have to add, right? I am hoping to avoid such things for relatively trivial functionality.  Is there anything within the existing gpackage?

Comment: @GeekedOut I don't believe any such thing exists in the standard libraries.

Comment: In reality it's not too much work to do this since it would just be a label with a background fading out over your main window. This library is just a couple of files and is easier than making it yourself.